# How can I create procedure in ESQL for select data from database

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I want to be able to enter a BankID into XML file and if record is exist then have integer result,if doesn't should display another result

My code is written in IBM web sphere message broker toolkit

Please help me about this simple problem!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET Environment.Variables.BankId =THE( SELECT BankId,                                          FROM 
                Database.YourSchema.YourTable where somecondition=true); 

    IF EXISTS(Environment.Variables.BankId[]) THEN
    SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.BankId=  Environment.Variables.BankId[1] ;
ELSE

   SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.BankId='SOMETHING ELSE';

END IF;
```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER
CAN you please say to me how can I use two option for search it on db not only use BankID , for example use bankid include bankName